# Visual studio build non-dependent projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have C++ and C# projects for MSBuild.

Dependencies are specified with `<ProjectReference>` tag in project files.

When I build specific project from command line using MSBuild, all goes right.

But when I build specific project A in Visual Studio 2010, some projects are rebuild on which project A does not depend.

What can cause such behavior and how to fix this?

Comment: set msbuild log level to diagnostic in VS settings and check log after described weird behaviour - it's usually pretty obvious what was the cause to trigger build.

Comment: I received 6000 lines output for my solution...

Comment: It's very detailed output and pretty straightforward =) . Now you can find exact spot where project was unexpectedly rebuild and what was the cause. It's not so hard after all  ;).

Answer (score 0):

It might be that one of the dependencies of Project-A depends on project. Visual studio would build all the dependencies down the line. e.g

Project A depends on Project-B & Project-C
Project-C depends on Project-X

Visual studio would build Project-X, Project-C, Project-B and Project-A.

dependency walker is a good utility to find out the dependency graph and the complete list.

Comment: why all are ok when building with MSBuild? What is a difference between Visual Studio and MSBuild when treating dependencies?

Comment: Visual studio is most often doing code search for references, so it will most likely build the all the projects. This article has some information on the MSBuild which might be helpful as well. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx

Comment: The issues described in article appear when solution file contains dependencies, but I have no dependencies in solution file - I wrote about this in question